# Why is my program crashing when I try to initialize my pointer?

Tags: c

So my program runs the numElements method but than crashes, am I declaring my variables wrong or is my pointer variable wrong?

Header.h

```
typedef struct Node {
int number;
struct Node *pNext;
}Node;
```

Other.h

```
void LinkedList(Node *pNode){

int i,j,c,numElem;
time_t t;
srand((unsigned) time(&t));
numElem = numElements();
pNode[numElem];

for(i = 0; i < numElem; i++){

    pNode[i].number = (rand() % (MAX - MIN)) + MIN;
    //c = (rand() % (MAX - MIN)) + MIN;
    printf("P is %d\n",pNode[i].number);
    printf("C = %d",c);

   }
}
```

Main.c

```
Node *pNode;
LinkedList(pNode);
```

Comment: do I need to initialize it to NULL at first?

Comment: Whats `pNode[numElem];`?

Comment: How did you declare and initialize `pNode`?

Comment: @tkausl that initializes the size so pNode[12];

Comment: @Cmi that's not an initialization. It's an access...

Comment: It doesn't. And `pNode` was never declared.

Comment: @litelite pNode is a pointer of Node that I pass through the functon

Comment: @Cmi and how does the caller initialize the memory for `pNode`?

Comment: We need to see the _entire function_.

Comment: @zwol Just edited it

Comment: @litelite I set the memory manually

Comment: please read this: [mcve]

Comment: @Cmi Show the code.

Comment: @litelite I just did

Comment: @Cmi you did not initialize any memory. You just created a dangling pointer. So (unless there is any other code in that function) `pNode[numElem];` will just access some random memory which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @litelite so my pNode[numElem] does nothing than?

Comment: @Cmi it reads a random adress in memory, that's what it does.

Comment: @Cmi,litelite More precisely, it _would_ read a random address in memory, but the value isn't used, so the compiler won't bother generating code to do anything at all because of that statement.

Comment: @zwol True, but it would in debug mode where the code is not optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed this `pNode = malloc(numElem * sizeof(Node));`

Comment: Good for you figuring this out for yourself, but do you realize that you have created an array, not a linked list?  (Maybe you _mean_ to make an array of linked list heads?)

Comment: @zwol I am making a linked list but am starting slow though

Comment: @zwol by the way is it better to use realloc?

Comment: realloc is for when you already have a chunk of memory allocated (by malloc) and you need to change how big it is.

Answer (score -1):

You need to allocate memory for pNode, for your case (C language) it could be,

```
pNode = malloc( numElem * sizeof(Node) );
```

The cast is not required for strict C, but for C++ it is.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: zwol, that depends on the compiler. so your classification is wrong! if, for example, it is necessary to compile with C++ also, it is requested to use the cast. I add C++ to my answer!

Comment: No, it doesn't depend on the compiler.

Comment: The question is about C only.  Casting the result of malloc is an actively bad practice in C and should never be encouraged.  Only when someone specifically requires code that can be compiled as both C and C++ should you include that cast.

Comment: No, it is not. The question is about C only.